# XSLT preceding sibling to limit foreach

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

A chunk of my xml is:

```
<svg>
<g id='NOCUT'>
<line x="5.0"/>
<line x="55.0"/>
<path x="50.0"/>
<line x="0.0"/>
<line x="55.0"/>
.
.
</g>
</svg>
```

In my xslt I should be able to read this list only until it encounters x=0; all the elements after it needs to be ignore.

I tried writing something as below, but it doesn't work:

```
<xsl:for-each select="svg[g/@id='NOCUT']">
<xsl:for-each select="g/*[preceding-sibling::node[line/@x = '0.0']]">
<xsl:value-of select="x"/>      
</xsl:foreach>
</xsl:foreach>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use

```
<xsl:for-each select="g/*[not(preceding-sibling::line[@x = '0.0'])]">
```

instead of

```
<xsl:for-each select="g/*[preceding-sibling::node[line/@x = '0.0']]">
```

also

change `<xsl:value-of select="x"/>` to `<xsl:value-of select="@x"/>`